# Proof of Darboux's Theorem. Questions (S.A. pp 137 question 5.2.6)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

[image]

I read https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192440/85079. The intuition's in the final paragrah.

> 1. I know how to prove this. But how can you presage to define $g(x) = f(x) - \alpha x$?
>
> **Unsanctioned:** Officially integrals haven't been presented hence I think this is unwarranted,
>   but I know $\color{magenta}{\int} f'(c) \; dx = \color{magenta}{\int} \alpha \; dx \implies f(c)= \alpha + constant$.
>
> **2.** The answer to (a) mentions (Fermat = Interior Extremum) Theorem underneath? Does (a) follow from this theorem, ergo no need to reprove it? Why does [Siminore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192440/85079) prove (a) anew?
>
> **3.** To prove $f'(a) \ge 0$ , [Siminore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192440/85079) takes $\color{darkred}{righthand}$ limit. To prove $f'(a) \ge 0$, $\color{seagreen}{\text{lefthand}}$.
>
> Why? Can I swap? To prove $f'(a) \ge 0$, take $\color{seagreen}{\text{lefthand}}$ instead? To prove $f'(a) \ge 0$, $\color{darkred}{righthand}$?
>   I know $g'(x) = \lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac {g\left( x+h\right) -g\left( a\right) } {h}$ exists $\iff$ left-hand = right-hand limit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your questions correctly.

1. The function $g$ is introduced just "to simplify matters" (as written above). It satisfies $g'(a)<0<g'(b)$, and the original problem is equivalent to finding som point $c$ such that $g'(c)=0$.
2. Siminore directly shows that the point $c$ does indeed exist. Part (a) of your exercise is intended to help you in finding where this point $c$ comes from. To show that $x$ and $y$ as above exist, use the definition of differentiability. You can write $g(x)=g(a)+(x-a)g'(a)+(x-a)\varepsilon (x)$, where $\varepsilon (x)\to 0$ as $x\to a^+$. Since $g'(a)<0$, you can find $\delta >0$ such that $g'(a)+\varepsilon(x)<0$ for every $x\in[0,\delta)$. Then $g(x)=g(a)+(x-a)(g'(a)+\varepsilon(x))<0$ for every $x\in (0,\delta)$. In the same way, you'll find that $g(y)<g(b)$ for every $y<b$ close enough to $b$.
3. Siminore does not talk about local min. His argument is that the function $g$ attains its maximum on $[a,b]$, and that it cannot be at $a$ or $b$. So it is attained at some $c\in (a,b)$ and hence Fermat's theorem can be used. In your setting, this is exactly the same except that you have to say that your function $g$ attains its *minimum* at some point $c\in [a,b]$. By part (a) of your exercise, $c$ can be equal neither to $a$ nor to $b$; so $c\in (a,b)$ and hence you can apply Fermat.

Comment: thanks for 3. i revised it. please apprise me?

Comment: **1,2**. Sorry...but these weren't my questions. For 1, I know it behaves and satisfies question. But where does it feyly issue from? For 2. I'm not catechizing about the proof of (a). Please read my question again and apprise me if you understand now?

Comment: For 1, I can't say anything else: $g$ is introduced to simplify matters. It is easier to deal with $0$ than with $\alpha$. As for 2, I still don't understand.

Comment: **2.** I want to know if (a) follows immediately from Fermat's Theorem that I posted. Siminore proved it and you proved it. But I don't want to reprove it. I want to know if proving Fermat's Theorem is stronger than (a)? If I prove Fermat's Theorem, did I prove (a)?

Comment: No, unless you argue as Siminore.