# If $f$ is differentiable and $\lim_{x→0} f'(x) = L$, then $f'(0) = L$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

True/False.
(c) If $f$ is differentiable on an interval containing zero and if $\lim_{x→0} f'(x) = L$, then $f'(0) = L$.

> **1.** How to presage proof by contradiction?

**Proof by contradiction.** True. Assume that $L 
\neq f'(0)$ and choose e > 0 so that $|f'(0) − L| > e$.
From the hypothesis that $\lim_{x→0} f'(x) = L$,
we know there exists a $δ > 0$ such that $0 < |x| < δ$ implies that $|f'(x) − L| < e$.
Now our choice of $e$ guarantees that there exists a point $f'(0) < a < \color{red}L$ but
$|a - L| > e$.

> **2.** How? We chose $e$ guarantee this?

However, by [Darboux’s Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/691235/85079), there exists a point x such that $|x| < d$ 
such that $f(x) = a$.

> **3.** How? $\color{red}L$ not a derivative of $f$? Ergo what sanctions use of Darboux's Theorem here?

This suggests that $a - L< e$, a contradiction.

> **4.** What suggests this?

Comment: Your method is good, but with minor mistakes. I have put a proof along the same approach.

Answer (score 11):

Let's try another way and salvage the proof which is suggested by OP. Suppose $\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x) = L$ and $f'(0) \neq L$. Also assume that $f'(0) < L$. The case $f'(0) > L$ can be handled similarly. let's take an $\epsilon$ with $0 < \epsilon < (L - f'(0))/2$. Now we have a $\delta > 0$ such that $$L - \epsilon < f'(x) < L + \epsilon\tag{1}$$ for all $x$ satisfying $0 < |x| < \delta$. Clearly by the definition of $\epsilon$ we can choose a number $A$ such that $f'(0) < A < L - \epsilon$. If $0 < |x| < \delta$ then we have $f'(0) < A < L - \epsilon < f'(x)$ and by Darboux theorem we have a value $c$ between $0$ and $x$ such that $f'(c) = A$.

Now the contradiction is obvious. We have $0 < |c| < \delta$ and $f'(c) = A < L - \epsilon$ and this contradicts $(1)$.

**Note**: What we have effectively proved is that *any function possessing intermediate value property can not have jump discontinuities.*

Comment: I have a doubt. In the proof above, we never really utilised the fact that the limit was taken to $0$. So can we just generalize this value of $0$ to any arbitrary $a\in\mathbb R$?

What I intend to mean is that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f'(x)=L$, then can we say that $f'(a)=L$ given that $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Excellent proof by the way! :D

Comment: P.S. (can't edit my comment so added it here): Another way to force the contradiction that I noticed that as you let $x\to 0$, then as $c\in(0,x)$, we get that $c\to 0$, then taking limits of $x\to 0$ on $f'(c)=A$, we can force a contradiction as it then forces $A=L$. :D

Answer (score 5):

According to Mean Value Theorem
$$
\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(\vartheta h),
$$
for some $\vartheta\in (0,1)$. But as $h\to 0$, the right-hand side of the above tends to 
$\lim_{h\to 0}f'(h)$. Therefore, $f$ the limit as $h\to 0$, of the left-hand side also exists, which means that $f$ is differentiable at $0$,
and it's derivative is equal to $\lim_{h\to 0}f'(h)$.